# Do we need sub-tags for Ghostbusters?

Tags: discussion, tags

I noticed that people have created [ghostbusters-1984](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghostbusters-1984) and [ghostbusters-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghostbusters-2016). I've edited the [ghostbusters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghostbusters) tag to make it clear that it can be used for the 2016 movie as well, but I'd prefer to stop the tags before they start if we decide against them.

Comment: Well, there's Ghostbusters and then there's... [uh... this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0127569). So maybe we do need subtags...

Comment: It's fairly telling that there have been almost no questions about the new ghostbusters film. I put that down to its excellent writing.

Comment: @Valorum - Do you mean excellent writing the same way as excellent moderating (that is, where nobody even notices it even happened?) :)

Comment: @dvk-in-exile - The reboot nobody asked for may yet spawn an unwanted flop sequel. All the while, Firefly remains cancelled. Go figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes.

In this instance it's perfectly possible that users may wish to have answers that relate specifically to the original film series and/or the rebooted film (which may yet [spawn a series](http://www.thewrap.com/ghostbusters-sequel-will-happen-sony/))

To that end, we should have tags for **both** sets of films as well as an overarching *franchise* tag that encompasses the two film series', the two TV series', various novels and other licensed properties.

Comment: Tag [tag:ghostbusters-the-flame-thrower]

Answer (score -3):

**No**.*

Given the low usage (only 18 questions) of the original tag of `Ghostbusters` we should be able to manage with just one tag for the entire franchise.

Some of our other tags that span different mediums (`Pokemon (x23)`, `Super Mario Brothers (x9)`, `Guardians of the Galaxy (x79)`) use only a franchise tag.

---

.* If the new franchise does spawn a mass of questions then it is possible the need for a new tag would arise. However, in its current state the answer should be no.

Comment: The only thing the new franchise seems to be spawning is apocalyptically bad reviews.

Comment: You are, perhaps unaware that [Guardians-of-the-Galaxy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guardians-of-the-galaxy) ***isn't*** a franchise tag. It's a ***film*** tag. The franchise tag is [Marvel-Cinematic-Universe](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe).

Comment: @Valorum So what do you tag the *Guardians of the Galaxy* comics with then?

Comment: Do we even have any GotG comic questions?

Comment: @Valorum just to be technical.... the tag usage info does not specify "film" and does *seem like* a franchise tag. Also, wouldn't their GotG work outside the MCU. If there are not, it may even reinforce my point that multiple tags for GB are not needed.

Comment: Also, sometimes I will post an opposite answer just so these questions have the proper balance

Comment: The purpose of a franchise tag is where there are multiple, potentially conflicting or non-canonical works based on the same property.

Comment: we currently have about half a dozen GotG comics-specific questions.

Comment: @Phantom42 - So it would seem that there's potentially a need to distinguish between the MCU GotG and the comic GotG.

Comment: @Valorum or one could use the GoTG and Comics tags?

Comment: @Skooba - The problems is that using a **Movies** tag with ghostbusters then leads us back to "*which movie?*"

Comment: I'm not going into the media tags discussion.

Comment: Guardians of Galaxy can be paired with either Marvel Cinematic Universe or Marvel Comics to denote which series it's referring to.